# Show pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(x-n)^2}$ converges pointwise

I can see that for $x=0$ the sum can be written as a geometric sum which then convergences, but I don't know how to approach from there

Comment: My guess: ratio test?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ratio test. The ratio of successive terms is $$\exp\left[{-(x-(n+1))^{2}}\right]/\exp\left[{-(x-n)^{2}}\right]=\exp\left[{-2n+2x-1}\right].$$ For any fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can take $n$ large enough so that this ratio is $<1$.

---

To elaborate, recall that the ratio test has to hold only for $n$ large enough (i.e. $n>N$) since 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}=\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}}_{\text{finite}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}a_{n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2+2xn-n^2)=\exp(-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp(2xn-n^2)$$
$$=\exp(-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(\exp(2x))^n\exp(-n^2)]\leq\exp(-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(\exp(2x))^n]$$

The last inequality follows from the fact that $\exp(-n^2)\leq 1$.